# cell touch misoperation of tableview in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I want to make it like this : when user touches a cell once, an apple appears, and touches same cell twice, apple disappears. but if I touch a cell 0, apple appears on not only the touched-cell, but also cell 8, cell 16 too. Same thing happens on cell 1,9,17 cell 2,10,18. when touches cell again, apples disappear simultaneously. don't know why this is happening.

I fixed this problem by the answer of Shubbank.

```
// I declare this on HelloWorld.h

int myArray[20];


// and this part is HelloWorld.cpp
// other codes..

void HelloWorld::tableCellTouched(TableView* table, TableViewCell* cell)
{

      log("cell number : %d", cell->getIdx());
     // i inserted for test. all cell have different idx number.

//add to the array if not found.
     if (myArray[cell->getIdx()] == 0) {
          myArray[cell->getIdx()] = 1;
     }
     else {
        myArray[cell->getIdx()] = 0;
     }

     auto touchedCell = cell->getChildByTag(2);
     if (myArray[cell->getIdx()] == 0)
     {
         touchedCell->setVisible(false);
     }
     else {
         touchedCell->setVisible(true);
     }
} 

Size HelloWorld::tableCellSizeForIndex(TableView* table, ssize_t idx)
{
    return Size(100, 90);
}

TableViewCell* HelloWorld::tableCellAtIndex(TableView* table, ssize_t idx)
{
    auto string = String::createWithFormat("%ld", idx);
    TableViewCell* cell = table->dequeueCell();

    if (cell == false)
    {
        cell = new CustomTableViewCell();
        cell->autorelease();

        auto apple = Sprite::create("apple.png");
        apple->setAnchorPoint(Point::ZERO);
        apple->setPosition(Point::ZERO);
        apple->setTag(2);
        apple->setVisible(false);
        cell->addChild(apple);

        auto label = LabelTTF::create(string->getCString(), "arial", 20.0);
        label->setAnchorPoint(Point::ZERO);
        label->setPosition(Point(5, 5));
        label->setTag(120);
        cell->addChild(label);
    }
    else {
        auto label = (LabelTTF*)cell->getChildByTag(120);
        label->setString(string->getCString());
    }

     auto touchedCell = cell->getChildByTag(2);
            if (myArray[cell->getIdx()] == 0)
            {
                touchedCell->setVisible(false);
            }
            else {
                touchedCell->setVisible(true);
            }

    return cell;
}

ssize_t HelloWorld::numberOfCellsInTableView(TableView* table)
{
    return 20;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the cell selection in a modal instead of manipulating the cell directly.

```
//declare a int[20] array in .h file
void HelloWorld::tableCellTouched(TableView* table, TableViewCell* cell)
{

    log("cell number : %d", cell->getIdx());
         // i inserted for test. all cell have different idx number.
    //add to the array if not found.
    if (myArray[cell->getIdx()] == 0) {
         myArray[cell->getIdx()] = 1
    }
    else {
       myArray[cell->getIdx()] = 0
    }
    auto touchedCell = cell->getChildByTag(2);
    if (myArray[cell->getIdx()] == 0)
    {
        touchedCell->setVisible(false);
    }
    else {
        touchedCell->setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

now in your tableCellAtIndex method change the visibility from modal

```
TableViewCell* HelloWorld::tableCellAtIndex(TableView* table, ssize_t idx) {
    // other code
     auto touchedCell = cell->getChildByTag(2);
    if (myArray[cell->getIdx()] == 0)
    {
        touchedCell->setVisible(false);
    }
    else {
        touchedCell->setVisible(true);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice... I did it just like you said, but it doesn't work.. seems like in the function tableCallAtIndex(), apple sprites are released several times simultaneously on different cells.

Comment: what does released mean ?

Comment: after i fail on method you adviced, i put codes below in tableCellTouched for test 

 if (myArray[cell->getIdx()] == 0) {
  
  auto touchedCell = cell->getChildByTag(2);
  touchedCell->setVisible(true);
 }
and remain tableCellAtIndex as first. As i click cell no.1, apple appears 1,9,17.. same thing happens.
I think those apple sprites are made when cells are made.

Comment: please update the question with the edit part so that i can see it formatted

Comment: you have not updated my code correctly , see the `tableCellTouched` method

Comment: yea firstly, I did it just like that. I declare int myArray[20]; on header also. the code i editted is after that. I tried to figure out when those apple sprites are made.

Comment: if you can just apply my code, i can go ahead and do tha changes for any fixes. currently you have not made my changes so i cant debug

Comment: Shubhank, I appreciate your advice anyways. I editted again like what i did right after I saw your answer

Comment: please mark my answer correct so you get 20 rep and then drop by to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow) to debug it there

Comment: I just got what you are suggesting.. OTL.. I am totally unfamiliar with this site. I already got 20 reputation, but still cannot texting give me some sec